# Is the question mark "?" internationally recognised as an icon for help?

Tags: icons, internationalisation, help

I'm looking to use "?" as my help button icon in a desktop application but I'm unsure how universally recognisable this will be.

I can localise this for different culture if necessary.

Any ideas?

Comment: You may want to read the following question: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/64920/info-icon-vs-question-mark

Comment: Thanks for the comment Bart. This is a full blown help system so the i icon would be inappropriate. My question is specifically to do with "?" being recognised internationally. Microsoft seem to indicate that it is: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742488(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @DaveBaldwin What does "a full blown help system" mean to you?

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2139/index.htm

Comment: What countries are you targeting?

Comment: That's completely open at the moment

Answer (score 10):

You're wondering whether the question-mark icon is universally recognised. There are two parts to this:

1. Do your users have prior experience with a question-mark icon?
2. Will your users recognize YOUR question-mark icon as offering Help?

I can only answer the first question. I did a quick search of the various style guides. To sum up:

- The **Microsoft Windows** UX guidelines identify [the question-mark icon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742488(v=vs.85).aspx) as an entry point for Help. This supports the use of a question mark.
- The **Google Android** (edited) as noted in the comments, also uses a [question mark for Help in the Material guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/icons/#ic_help).
- The **Apple OS X** (edited) human interface guidelines show [the question mark is standard for Help on the Mac](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/ControlsButtons.html).

Many people worldwide have been exposed to Microsoft products (edit) and Apple iOS products for years. Then again, many users are first exposed to technology via their smart phone where, despite the standard Question mark, the Help itself is less commonly provided.

As is often the case, the answer to your question is "it depends" because you don't identify the type of user, their prior experience, the type of device, and so on.

I hope these thoughts help you make a decision, or help you to focus your research.

You can do some quick research, for example by posting an image of a series of icon choices in [Chalkmark](https://www.optimalworkshop.com/chalkmark.htm), and asking people who represent your users to identify which icon signifies Help to them. Research is the best way to answer this kind of question, because when it comes to predicting usability, opinions—even of experts—are only correct part of the time.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. After a bit more digging I've seen that os x also uses the ? as a help button. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/ControlsButtons.html. I'm going to keep the question open for now as this doesn't quite answer the question in the title.

Comment: Thanks for posting the info on the "?" for Help in OS X. That just leaves Android. If the major platforms use this, then it becomes less a question of "Will this be recognized internationally" and more a question of "Do we follow the standard on other things but not on this?" A UI is full of things that not every member of every audience recognises or knows how to use. That's a different problem. I favour following the standard, as you might guess. :)

Comment: There's an argument to say that an application shouldn't need help as it should be intuitive enough. I see it as a place for workflow tips and usage scenarios.

Comment: Android uses a "?" as well: https://www.google.com/design/icons/#ic_help

Comment: Excellent, so if all three major platforms HAVE a question-mark icon, then the focus turns to the core question: will users RECOGNISE its function? As with all icons, the key it it to present it with a text label. Windows Phone has a clever way to solve this problem without wasting precious real-estate on small devices: be default, it shows only icons in the task bar, and, when the user expands the task bar, the text labels appear for each button, temporarily.

Comment: @DaveBaldwin: In addition, an application can be as intuitive as it may, as a user, I still occasionally wish for a readable confirmation that a particular feature actually does exactly what I have figured to be the probable (intuitive) way it works. Moreover, every software has its limits, so in a way, no software will ever be intuitive, as there will always be a boundary of the featureset that I will run into (from a user's PoV, "intuitively", their particular use case should always be completely supported), and help is *the* place to get informed about all of these limitations beforehand.